# Webservice C# JSON to Arduino

Tags: web-service

I have a project in Microsoft Visual Studio C# and I have to pass JSON data to my Arduino via Ehternet Shield.

This is how it works:
[image]

Is it possible? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If you're using an Ethernet Shield, you should be able to run a webserver on the Arduino and simple do an HTTP request from your C# webservice to the Arduino.

Check this tutorial on how to write a webserver for arduino using the ethernet shield: http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/WebServer

Doing an HTTP request of any kind from C# should be easy enough and is not in the scope of this site.